# QT and OpenGL how to integrate properly and display a texture

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, graphics

I have a few questions about using them both. At the moment I have a preexisting renderer I'm trying to use with QT and OpenGL.

A few questions are:

1. How can I get my results to draw in a QGraphicsScene? Is that even the right output to attempt to be using.
2. With OpenGL I want to be able to load textures and then be displayed in a window? Do I need to coordinate where to draw the texture or can I just say in the centre of a QWidget?
3. What paramenter would I usually need, I persume I need a Gluint for the texture, and then parameters for the size?

At the moment my results are quite poor, it seems to render something but basically not either in the correct window or not in the window of choice and basically it seems to 'hide' text e.g. hello, I can only see e. Odd I think.

Comment: See my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335218/using-qimage-with-opengl

Comment: @Lucas review your other questions and **ACCEPT** some answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this link will help you code with Qt and OpenGL:

http://wesley.vidiqatch.org/03-08-2009/nehe-opengl-lessons-in-qt-chapter-1-and-2

I used this and the NeHe tutorial to code a small Qt/OpenGL application, so all information you need is contained in both tutorials.