# Using QImage to create a texture for OpenGL 4.5

Tags: c++, opengl, qt5

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335218/using-qimage-with-opengl) seems to be asking the exact question, but it is asked in 2011 uses QGLWidget which is an outdated method, with the fixed pipeline.

I'm getting incorrect results when using QImage like this, where the texture image looks corrupted. Obviously, something is off and the bits are not returned in the expected RGB format. How do I use QImage correctly in this use case?

```
QImage img(texture.file_path.c_str());
unsigned char* actual_texture_img = img.bits();
int width = img.width();
int height = img.height();

if (!actual_texture_img) {
    return -1;
}

GLuint texture_id;
glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, actual_texture_img);

glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

sample image with incorrect texture:

[image: Incorrect texture loading]

Comment: It [appears](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#Format-enum) Qt stores non-palette colour images in 32bit format, setting alpha to 0xff if it isn't available. `GL_RGB` expects 3 bytes per pixel. Either use GL_RGBA or convert to 24bpp manually (but be careful with row pitch - lines should be aligned to 32bit (can be disabled with separate GL call)).

Comment: Agh it actually can be RGB888. Or not. Sorry, check your format first then.

Answer (score 1):

I have identified the fix for this. Interestingly, QImage in QT 5.11 (maybe in other versions too), defaults to loading images in the 32-bit ARGB format. So, I'm expecting the RGB 24-bit format or RGB_888, as input to glTexImage2D. The simple fix is to convert the image using the QImage function `convertToFormat` like so:

```
    img = img.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

It was a case of my openGL format, GL_RGB not matching the loaded format.